Binary digital sum (Hamming weight) of Arithmetic Progression
Context
I was recently going through the Putnam 2023 problems and the topic of this post is question $\text{B2}$ from there.

For each positive integer $n$, let $k(n)$ be the number of ones in the binary representation of $(2023\cdot n)$.
What is the minimum value of $k(n)$?

Now, the given solution takes a brute force approach, showing that $k(n)$ can’t be equal to $1$ or $2$ and then giving example of a case where $k(n)$ equals $3$.
However their approach is not easily generalizable, and I am looking for something better.

Problem
Given a non-negative integer $x$, define $C(x)$ to be the binary digital sum of $x$ (the number of ones in the binary representation of $x$).
Now for a particular non-negative integer $n$, consider the following sequence: $$ C(n) , C(2n), C(3n) , \cdots , C(kn) , \cdots $$
What can we say about the pattern followed in this particular sequence?

Modified Thue-Morse sequence
Let us consider the sequence $ C(0) , C(1) , C(2) , \cdots $
Simplifying each term, we get this sequence:
$$0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,1,2,2,3,2,3,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,4,4,5,\cdots$$
This is the OEIS $\text{A000120}$ sequence. This sequence is reminiscent of the Thue-Morse sequence. While the Thue-Morse sequence takes the current string and adds its complement at the end of the string, in this sequence we have to add the element-wise successor of the string at the end of the current string. It can be easily shown that this corresponds to the idea of binary digital sum.

Finally…
However, this pattern breaks down as soon as we take the sequence $C(x), C(2x), C(3x), …$ where $x$ isn’t a perfect power of $2$.
For example, for the sequence $C(0),C(3),C(6),C(9),...$ we get OEIS $A036555$:
$$0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5, 6, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 5, 4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 6, 5, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6,...$$
OEIS $A046820$ is the sequence $C(0), C(5), C(10),...$

My question is, what can we comment about the sequence $C(0), C(x), C(2x), C(3x),...$ for any $x$ in general?
This might seem a bit open-ended, but I am looking for anything that might be of interest regarding the sequence: Patterns that appear in the sequence, generating function, etc.

Even after setting the bounty, this question has not received as much response as I had hoped for. Could someone please tell if this might be better suited on Math Overflow?

A086342 (https://oeis.org/A086342) and the links therein might be relevant.  I don't personally know anything about this - but I computed the minimum of the sequence of $C(kn)$ for each $n$ sequence out to n = 12 and that was enough to find it.  The 2020 paper "Computational Aspects of Sturdy and Flimsy Numbers" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.02731) contains a lot of references.

What are you looking for here ? Minimum value occurring in the list ? Algorithmic formula to calculate the terms ? Inequality Constraints ? Something else ?

@Prem I have edited the post and added the details.

NEW Claim :
Here is a Claim I made up , not sure whether it is already known :
When we are given some $n$ & some $m$ , we can always get some $x$ such that $C(1x),C(2x),C(3x),C(4x),C(5x),C(6x),\cdots,C(mx)$ are all at least $n$.
Proof is easy , though I would like to add it later , in case somebody wants to try it out.
NEWER Claim :
We can more-over get arbitrarily large $z$ such that $C(zx+1x),C(zx+2x),C(zx+3x),C(zx+4x),C(zx+5x),C(zx+6x),\cdots,C(zx+mx)$ are all at least $n$.
In other words , these consecutive elements occur repeatedly , with varying Starting Points.
Proof is easy & minor modification of earlier case.
I will add it all later , in 2 days time.

I apologize, I should have instead asked for how the terms in the series relate to one another, any particular pattern that appears, any way to analyse the series given some specific constraints. Algorithms are too simple to be of any importance. Deleting my previous comment in the question, sorry again.

Yes , that was why I said "algorithmic formula" was very easy , in my Post. The "new claim" might be more along the lines of what you want , @SohamSaha , if that is indeed so , I will edit with the "newer claim" that we can get those consecutive elements repeatedly in that list.

Yes you should edit your post with the newer claim, along with a proof (if you’d like)

Edited accordingly , @SohamSaha , + removed the unnecessary Section !
